# Not able to propagate theme to nested navigator expo react native paper on devices (web works)

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-native-paper

It is weird. My app on browser works perfectly, but on iOS simulator, and Expo Go, it does not:
[image]
[image]

And the problem seems to be only with the background color, as the colors for light theme are different:
[image]

> But note that still the theme does not apply for the tab navigation itself. On web it does apply.

What I have is the Main component, that adds the PaperProvider:

```js
import { Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import themes from './constants/themes';
import MainStackNavigation from './navigation/MainStackNavigation';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

const Main = () => {
    const theme= 'dark';
    const _theme = themes[theme];
    const session = true;

    return (
        <PaperProvider theme={_theme}>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <NavigationContainer linking={ {prefixes: []}} theme={_theme}>
                    {session ? (
                        <MainStackNavigation />
                    ) : (
                        <></>
                    )}
                </NavigationContainer>
            </Provider>
        </PaperProvider>
    );
};
```

Here is the theme configuration:

```js
import {
    DarkTheme as NavigationDarkTheme,
    DefaultTheme as NavigationDefaultTheme,
} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { MD3DarkTheme, MD3LightTheme, adaptNavigationTheme } from 'react-native-paper';
import { darkGreenColors, lightGreenColors } from '../utils/colors';


const { LightTheme, DarkTheme } = adaptNavigationTheme({
    reactNavigationLight: NavigationDefaultTheme,
    reactNavigationDark: NavigationDarkTheme,
});

const CombinedDefaultTheme = {
    ...MD3LightTheme,
    ...LightTheme,
    ...lightGreenColors,
};

const CombinedDarkTheme = {
    ...MD3DarkTheme,
    ...DarkTheme,
    ...darkGreenColors,
};

const themes = {
    light: CombinedDefaultTheme,
    dark: CombinedDarkTheme
};


export default themes;
```

And, most importantly, the navigation:

```js
import React from 'react';

import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-native-paper/react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { useTheme } from 'react-native-paper';


import PlantsScreen from '../screens/PlantsScreen';
import HandPlant from '../svgs/HandPlant';
import NotificationsScreen from '../screens/NotificationsScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

const BottomBarNavigation = () => {
    const { colors } = useTheme();
    const _barStyle = 'dark-content';

    return (
        <>
            <StatusBar
                barStyle={_barStyle}
                backgroundColor={colors.background}
                animated
            />
            <Tab.Navigator>
                <Tab.Screen
                    name="plants"
                    component={PlantsScreen}
                    options={{
                        tabBarIcon: () => <HandPlant height={24}/>,
                        tabBarLabel: 'Plants',
                    }}
                />
            </Tab.Navigator>
        </>
    );
};

const MainStackNavigation = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} >
                <Stack.Screen name="home" component={BottomBarNavigation} />
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="notifications"
                    component={NotificationsScreen}
                    options={{
                        presentation: 'modal'
                    }}
                />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </>
    );
};

export default MainStackNavigation;
```

What I figured is that the theme is not being propagated to the TabNavigator, since the NotificationsScreen is working.
[image]

As it works on web, it is very difficult to figure out what is going on... Does anyone have any ideas?